# Referencing a named range by formula in data validation

Tags: excel, validation, dynamic, range, formula

Hello wonderful people.

I have a series of named ranges, `A_Colours`, `B_Colours`, etc.
These represent sections of a sorted column in a colour list, sorted by codes for the manufacturer that makes those colours. These are dynamic named ranges, constructed by `COUNTA` for how many colours have that mfr code. By my calculation, the list should be contiguous, since the column is sorted by code.

I know I can reference the ranges in Data Validation by simply setting `=A_Colours` as the list source (no quotes). This **does work** in this case.

However, I have a dropdown to control which A-M range I want to show in the child dropdown.
So, e.g. dropdown in A1 shows A, B, C, D as options.
Dropdown in B1 shows dropdown options relative to the chosen option in A1.

**EXAMPLE:**
I select A from the list in A1.
In cell B1, I want my dropdown to show all values from named range `A_Colours`.

I have tried all manner of ways to pass the text string A_Colours to the DV list source field, but all have failed. Either error in formula, or the range evaluates to an error, or it allows me to select only A_Colours from the dropdown.

**Example 1:**
A1 choose A
B1 DV box:

```
=INDIRECT("$A$1")&"_Colours"
```

This gives error "The list source must be a delimited list, or a reference to single row or column."

Could this be because the table list is sorted? I don't think so because the very first example above works.

**Example 2:** use helper cell in C1 to create text string "A_Colours", by formula:
=$A$1&"_Colours"

Then in DV box for cell B1:

```
=INDIRECT("$C$1")
```

Please help me achieve this!
Thank you.

[Edit] SOLUTION:

Create new sheet as directed below.
Create header for each manufacturer ("A" in cell A1).
Enter formula into A2 (as an array formula, Ctrl+Shift+Enter):

=INDEX(Colours, SMALL(IF((INDEX(Colours, , 1)=INDEX(MFR,MATCH(A$1,MFR[MFRName],0),2)), MATCH(ROW(Colours), ROW(Colours)), ""), ROWS($B$1:B1)), COLUMNS($A$1:$B1))

I adapted it a bit, but credit for this goes to https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/28/extract-all-rows-from-a-range-that-meet-criteria-in-one-column-in-excel/

Apply the formula down to the last plus a few to allow for expansion.
Apply the formula across to your last header.

Now you have lists which are definitely contiguous and single-column and not dynamic, so meet the stringent criteria for data validation.

Create a named range for each list, using the exact name keeps it simple but I chose to add "Name" to the end, e.g. Mfr1Colours.

Reference them in the DV source list field (for cell B2 in our original sheet) like:
=INDIRECT($B$2&"Colours")

What this does:
Looks in the Colours table:
MFR Code     Colour     Code

Finds the first matching instance of the MFR Code in cell A1 of our original sheet ("A") from the Manufacturer table "MFR", which has columns:
MFRName     Code

Pulls out the row by the MATCH(ROW(Colours,Row(Colours),"").

Checks which row and column you want by the ROWS and COLUMNS at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a spare, helper range, where you would make a simple codetable with 2 columns - `Color_Reference`, `Color_Names` and name it `c_colors`:

```
A A_Colour
B B_Colour
C C_Colour
```

You could use this in CV list configuration for dropdoon on cell B1:

```
=INDIRECT(VLOOKUP(A1;c_colors;2;FALSE))
```

Try to look at the examples here, it may help you as well: http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I ended up doing. It was a messy workaround because I had to find the elements of the table. Will update the question with how I did that, but yours answers my question so I'll mark it done.